# What is the next number in the series?

Tags: lateral-thinking, number-sequence, sequence

What is the next number of this series?

> 1 , 4 , 5 , 6 , 7 , 9 , 11 ?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

These are...

> numbers not containing the letter "T". The next one is 100.

Answer (score -1):

I know this has already been solved but I have found another solution.

> 1,4 - 14 
>  41+15=5,6 - 56 reverse of 56 is 65
>  
>  
>  65+14= 79
>  
>  97+13=110
>  
>  11, 0
>  
>  0 can be the answer!

Comment: Ideally, for such a short sequence, you want the explanation to be a simple as possible. There seem to be three different operations (concantenation, digit reversal and splitting) and two arbitrary constants (the first 15 and the difference of -1) which is overkill and it seems like you could almost fit any number you wanted by going to such lengths.